# Selecting rows with GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL in a specific order

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "tblVersion" that looks something like...

```
| key           |  value  |
|-------------------------|
| buildVersion  |  5      |
| minorVersion  |  4      |
| majorVersion  |  2      |
```

I want to build a query that will return the string "2.4.5", i.e. majorVersion.minorVersion.buildVersion.

So far I have

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tblVersion.value SEPARATOR '.' ) AS softwareVersion 
FROM tblVersion 
WHERE tblVersion.key = 'majorVersion'
OR tblVersion.key = 'minorVersion' OR tblVersion.key = 'buildVersion'
```

This returns "5.2.4" and I can't seem to get the string in the correct order.

Is it possible to be specific about the order the values are displayed?

Comment: What is the correct order? Remember that (with some important qualifications) there is no row order in MySQL.

Comment: The correct order is major then minor then build, in the example above this gives 2.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use order by `FIELD`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value order by  FIELD(tblVersion.key , 'majorVersion', 'minorVersion' , 'buildVersion') SEPARATOR '.' ) AS softwareVersion 
FROM tblVersion
WHERE tblVersion.key = 'majorVersion'
OR tblVersion.key = 'minorVersion' OR tblVersion.key = 'buildVersion';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ef367/4

Comment: That doesn't work - or rather, it works only by coincidence - as [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ef367/5) demonstrates

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a `CASE` expression in the `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
select
  group_concat(`value` 
               order by 
                 case `key` 
                   when 'majorVersion' then 0 
                   when 'minorVersion' then 1
                   else 'buildVersion' end SEPARATOR '.') SoftwareVersion
from tblVersion
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a297/2)

Answer (score 0):

If DhruvPathak is on the right lines in regards to what you're actually after, then that can be achieved this way...

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(x.value ORDER BY FIELD(x.key,'minorversion','majorversion','buildversion') DESC SEPARATOR '.') softwareVersion 
  FROM tblversion x 
 WHERE x.key IN('minorVersion','majorVersion','buildVersion');
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for me, when plugged into fiddle still returns 5.2.4

Comment: See if you can figure out what needs to change.